# Explanation of output of the command in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, pipe

I was trying out certain commands on the linux terminal and I could not understand the output for the following command:

```
wc < sfddfs |& wc
sfddfs: No such file or directory.
0 0 0
```

Here sfddfs is a file which does not exist. Why does it give the output `0 0 0.`

When contents of file of sfddfs is passed to wc, it finds the file does not exist, and it will give the error output (written on StdError) which is passed through pipe to next wc. So shouldnt wc calculate the with the output on StdError?i.e. `1 6 34`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
wc < nosuchfile
```

it is not `wc` complaining about the missing file, it's the shell you're running. The *shell* is trying to open `nosuchfile` so it can connect it to the standard input file handle, without `wc` even knowing that's happened - as far as it's concerned, there should be no difference between standard input from the terminal or redirected from a file.

This attempted connection happens long before the `wc` program is actually loaded into the process space and hence the shell reports the error. And, in fact, the `wc` is not even run in that case, something you can confirm with:

```
( echo X ) < nosuchfile
```

No `X` is output here because the sub-shell that would echo it is never executed. A more obvious example is:

```
sleep 60 < nosuchfile
```

which plainly *doesn't* sleep for 60 seconds.

And, because `wc` is not run in this case, the *second* `wc` in the full command sequence receives an empty stream, prompting it to give you `0 0 0` as the output.

Comment: wc < sfddfs. When the error occurs for this, why does not the error received by this be caught by stderr ?
     
From what I am understanding the output goes to stdout rather than stderr. But why is it so ? Why cant stderr handle this? Subsequently in which case does stderr handle the errors and which case does stdout handle the errors?

Comment: @user1692342, because `bash` processes redirections _in order,_ meaning that `xyzzy 2>&1 >plugh` is _not_ the same thing as `xyzzy >plugh 2>&1`.

Comment: Rather, the message is going to the *shell*'s standard error, not `wc`'s standard error (which is the stream that is captured by `|&`).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is shell redirections are done in turn.  Consider:

```
wc < sfddfs |& wc
```

The error from the redirection of stdin occurs **before** stderr is redirected.  Hence, the error appears on the terminal and is not fed to `wc`.

By contrast, observe:

```
$ wc 2>&1 < sfddfs | wc
      1       7      40
```

By redirecting stderr before redirecting stdin, we have changed the outcome.  When the error occurs opening `sfddfs`, the error message is sent to `wc`.

There are other ways of affecting the order in which the shell does the redirections.  One is by grouping statements:

```
$ { wc < sfddfs; } |& wc
      1       7      40
```

Or,

```
$ ( wc < sfddfs ) |& wc
      1       7      40
```

In both cases, the redirection of stderr occurs *before* the grouped statements start to execute.  Hence, `wc` captures the error message.

Comment: wc < sfddfs. When the error occurs for this, why does not the error received by this be caught by stderr ?

Comment: From what I am understanding the output goes to stdout rather than stderr. But why is it so ? Why cant stderr handle this? Subsequently in which case does stderr handle the errors and which case does stdout handle the errors?

Comment: The error is always sent to whichever stderr is _currently active_ when the error occurs.  It is true that, in some of the examples, stderr is redirected into stdout.  That is, for example, what `|&` does: it sends stderr to stdout.